# how to remove button's background color when pressed - xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I want to remove the button background color when it is pressed and like to have transparent background since I am using image as a background.
Able to remove the border while mouse hover by the following code:

```
btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
btn.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and by setting:

```
btn.Background = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
```

However I'm unable to remove the background while clicking on it, it is showing a gray colored background.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried targetButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter what you set, the [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109) will (should) override your value due to the `Pressed` state of the `CommonStates` `VisualStateGroup`.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <!-- This will cause the gray background color of the button -->
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                KeyTime="0"
                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Instead of setting the color - as well as the border, how you're doing it right now - from code behind, you should create your own template for the buttons, setting the `Background` to the desired value, e.g. `Transparent`.

Comment: Yes found it already, removed the story board itself. Thanks though

Comment: @Sudha You may approve an answer, or close the question :)

Comment: @Herdo Is there a way to remove backgrounds of all buttons via a style etc.?

Comment: @Shimmy Sure, just have to set the default style for buttons.